# Possible null reference argument for parameter 'connectionString' in 'DbContextOptionsBuilder SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions..UseSqlServer

Tags: asp.net-core

I am using visual studio 2022 and asp.net .net core 6 to build a microservices. I am getting
Possible null reference argument for parameter 'connectionString' in 'DbContextOptionsBuilder SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, string connectionString, Action? sqlServerOptionsAction = null)'

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your connection string defined in your appsettings.json file?

For instance, your appsettings.json file should look something like this:

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "place your connection string here."
    },
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
        }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Comment: Here is my appsettings.json settings

Comment: {
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=.;Database=RestaurentAPI;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }  
}

Comment: Your DBContext has two constructors, right? Like this:
public MyDBContext()
        {
        }

        public MyDBContext(DbContextOptions<MyDBContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

Comment: Also, my program.cs looks like this:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using TestMVCWebApplicationWithEF;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDBContext>(options =>
 options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

var app = builder.Build();
Not seeing the same warning with a Visual Studio 2022, .NET 6, MVC project.

Comment: I have similar program.cs file but still having warning    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
               options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));